# Format and partition second hard drive using terminal? (Ubuntu Server 14.04)

Tags: command-line, server, partitioning, hard-drive, format

this is my first question on here...

So, I’ve installed Ubuntu server 14.04 (32 bit) on a VirtualBox virtual PC. Originally i just made it with a 32gb virtual HDD so since then I’ve created a new virtual HDD which is 100gb and I’ve added it to the virtual machine in VirtualBox

What I can't figure out is how do I format and partition this new hard drive from a CLI? I can't install a GUI so need to use CLI

*Anyone able to guide me in the right direction for this?*

Answer (score 13):

**Solved**

I used

```
  fdisk -l
```

to show the partitions and then:

```
  fdisk /dev/sdb

  n

  p 

  1

  [enter]

  [enter]

   w
```

and then:

```
   mkntfs /dev/sdb1
```

in that order to partition the drive. obviously if anyone used they replace `sdb` and `sdb1` to their own if needed.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please review [my edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/587458/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... ;-)  (And 2 upvotes!)  >:)